# Need to insert new key value pairs recursiverly inside every children json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, recursion

i have a nested json array of objects:

```
$json_url_data = [{
    "form_name": "z1",
    "name":"name1",
    "children": [{
        "form_name": "z2",
        "name":"name2",
        "children": [{
            "form_name": "z3",
            "name":"name2"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

i want to dynamically insert a new key value pair, which should look some thing like this:

```
[{
    "form_name": "z1",
    "name":"name1",
    "peopleCount": "125,678,190",
    "children": [{
        "form_name": "z2",
        "name":"name2",
        "peopleCount": "156,987",
        "children": [{
            "form_name": "z3",
            "name":"name2",
            "peopleCount": "678,098"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

And i tried using recursion like below, but wasnt able to achieve the above result:

```
function print_data($menu,  $depth) {
    foreach ($menu as $value) {
        $deepid =  '\"'.$value['form_name'].'\"';

        $api_call_var = '{{i have a apiu call proxy here}}';
        $read_data = file_get_contents($read_data);
        $read_data = json_decode($read_data, true);
        $value['peopleCount'] = $read_data['count']; // after decode read the count

        $obj_array[] = $value;
        if (is_array($value['children'])) {
            print_data ($value['children'],$depth+1);
        }
    }//end of for each

}//end of function
print_data ($json_url_data,  0);
```

i am stuck for hours, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue. When updating same array, you need to receive parameters as reference and update the same array in recursion.

Here is the code. I've added 123 as peopleCount but you add value using the API call.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$json_url_data = json_decode('[{
    "form_name": "z1",
    "name":"name1",
    "children": [{
        "form_name": "z2",
        "name":"name2",
        "children": [{
            "form_name": "z3",
            "name":"name2"
        }]
    }]
}]', true);

function print_data(&$menu) {
    foreach($menu as &$value) {
        $value['peopleCount'] = 123; // using some API call add peopleCount value here
        if(isset($value['children'])) {
            print_data($value['children']);
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}

print_r(print_data($json_url_data));
```

And this is the output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [form_name] => z1
            [name] => name1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [form_name] => z2
                            [name] => name2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [form_name] => z3
                                            [name] => name2
                                            [peopleCount] => 123
                                        )

                                )

                            [peopleCount] => 123
                        )

                )

            [peopleCount] => 123
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode('[{
    "form_name": "z1",
    "name":"name1",
    "peopleCount": "125,678,190",
    "children": [{
        "form_name": "z2",
        "name":"name2",
        "peopleCount": "156,987",
        "children": [{
            "form_name": "z3",
            "name":"name2",
            "peopleCount": "678,098"
        }]
    }]
}]', TRUE);
function countTotal($data) {
    if(is_array($data)){
        foreach($data as $row){
            $row['peopleCount'] = 0;///here total val
            if(isset($row['children']) {
                countTotal($row['children']);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $data['peopleCount'] = 0;//here total val
    }
}
countTotal(&$arr);
```